# Custom social share not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WkS9V/2/)

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://www.google.com&p[images][0]=http://www.hdwallpapers3g.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Audi-A1.jpg&p[title]=Sharing%20custom%20title&p[summary]=Custom%20text%20description">Share on Facebook</a>
```

When posted on Facebook, why won't the custom title,description and image work? It just automatically takes that from the link and ignore custom settings when posted on FB.

Is there any other working JS/Jquery solution for this perhaps?

Comment: Passing custom parameters through the "sharer" doesn't work anymore, switch to `FB.ui` `feed` method (which requires an app id) or just use OG meta tags

Comment: @AdamAzad OG meta is not an option in my example. Can you share more on this FB.ui solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to force overwriting `og` meta tags is by using `FB.ui` with `feed` method **which requires an app id and limits a lot of features like ability to choose post to friend's timeline, group or a fan page you administrate, however, I recommend using Open Graph as the best solution tags!**

### HTML

```
<div class="container"> 
    <a id="shareOnFB" class="shareBtn">Share on Facebook</a>
</div>
```

### JS

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'XXXXXXXXXX', // Your App ID
        status: false,
        xfbml: false,
        logging: false
    });

    $('#shareOnFB').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'Retrogram',
            link: 'https://www.facebook.com/Retrogram',
            picture: 'http://i.imgur.com/SKwsQM2.png'
        });
    });
};
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAzad/ZKNr4/)</kbd>